# Can't connect with admin user after CouchDB fresh install on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, couchdb, ubuntu-12.04

I have a CouchDB installing issue on Ubuntu 12.04, actually is not an installing issue, but configuring. After installed with

```
sudo apt-get couchdb
```

I edit `/etc/couchdb/local.ini` and add

```
adminuser = mypass
```

to the `[admin]` section and then I try

```
 curl http://adminuser:mypass@127.0.0.1:5984
```

but I get

```
{"error":"unauthorized","reason":"Name or password is incorrect."}
```

Of course, I restarted the server after edited `local.ini`

I tried what says here too: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Installing_on_Ubuntu :
 "fix problems where adding admin hangs or setting admins in `local.ini`..." but still no luck :(

After that I tested with lastest version from `git` but the error is still present. I have to say that after rebooting Ubuntu it works, but I need that this work out of the box without rebooting for an install script.

Comment: The correct section name is [`[admins]`](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/config/auth.html#server-administrators) (with an s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's safer to modify the .ini files using _config as that will follow all the escaping and spacing rules (in your case the spaces around = are probably the problem)

```
curl -X PUT localhost:5984/_config/admins/adminuser -d '"mypass"'"
```